# How can I save the source code of a solidity smartcontract from the ethereum blockchain in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, solidity, etherscan

I'm looking for a quick way to get the source code of a smartcontract. I tried using the following python code:

```py
import requests
import json

address = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413"
api_key = my_api_key
request_string = f'''https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address={address}&apikey={api_key}'''

response = requests.get(request_string)
print(response.text)
data = json.loads(response.text)['result'][0]['SourceCode']


file = open("contract.sol", "w")
a = file.write(data)
file.close()
```

So while this works for the given address, it doesn't work if the source code consists of multiple files (like with this address: 0xED5AF388653567Af2F388E6224dC7C4b3241C544). So is there a quick and easy way to save all of them into one file? Or do I just have to create a separate file for each one of the files?

Comment: The source code of the smart contract is not available on Ethereum blockchain. Only its bytecode is.